# Why does haskell throw this error?

Tags: haskell

Trying to write function that numerize items of list and returns list of tuples with numbers, ya I know I can do it with 'zip' function, but task is to write it with recursion: so I get

> cannot construct an infinite type: a = [a] when generalizing type(s) for numerize'

What am I doing wrong?

```
numerize' :: [a] -> Int -> [(a, Int)]
numerize' [] _ = []
numerize' [x] n = [(x, n)]
numerize' [x:xs] n = (x, n) : numerize' xs (n + 1)
```

Comment: You do not need the singleton case!

Comment: I wouldn't use the term "throw" for compiler errors. "throwing" an error usually refers to runtime exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[x:xs]
```

should be

```
(x:xs)
```